# function not called after state is set

Tags: react-native, state

When onPress if called => I am trying to call `fetchCryptoStats` but it's not being called after the state is set.I need the updated `selectedItem' to pass into the function.
I was reading into the lifecycle hooks and this was the guidance I received but the function is not being called ... any advice?

```
<ListItem
            bottomDivider={true}
            onPress={() => {
              this.setState(
                {
                  setModalVisible: true,
                  selectedItem: symbol.toUpperCase(),
                },
                function () {
                  console.log(this.state.selectedItem);
                  this.fetchCryptoStats(this.state.selectedItem);
                },
              );
            }}>
```

Comment: Add a console.log to that function and try again, tell to us if they print anything

Comment: @LucasVazquez console log does not even get called

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is create a function and execute your function fetchCryptoStats get the answer then push in your new state

in that enviroment you can not use this state `this.state.selectedItem`  because is async `useState`, that does not yet updated, you should use this `symbol.toUpperCase()` because its the same value

```
selectedItem: symbol.toUpperCase()
```

then your code will be like this

```
const handlePress=()=>{
const newVar = this.fetchCryptoStats(symbol.toUpperCase()) //here
const newState= {
                  setModalVisible: true,
                  selectedItem: symbol.toUpperCase(),
                  yourAttribute: newVar,
                }

               this.setState(newState);
}


onPress={handlePress}
```

Comment: I tried this does not work, what is yourAttribute supposed to be?

Comment: I need the answer of state.selectedItem

Comment: @FrankBoccia in that enviroment you can not use that state because is async useState, you should use this symbol.toUpperCase()